# How can I remove dynamic data in string before a value in that string? / using Lodash's _.trimStart with dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, string, lodash, trim

I'm working `urls` returned from a server that I have no control over where and sometimes the `urls` return with extra data at the front.
For instance

sometimes it returns this

`https://example.com/image/5119b3905.jpg`

and this I can use, but sometimes it will return something like this

`https://d1yww.cloudfront.net/9MA=/670x670/example.com/image/5119b3905.jpg`

where I'd like to use remove everything before the `example.com` and to do that I could use something like lodash's `_.trimStart` method something like

```
    _.trimStart('https://d1yww.cloudfront.net/9MA=/670x670/example.com/image/5119b3905.jpg',
   'd1yww.cloudfront.net/9MA=/670x670');
```

but the `d1yww.cloudfront.net/9MA=/670x670'` is never static for me to do this and I don't know how to grab the dynamic data to use `_.trimStart` and I don't see any other useful lodash's methods and I don't know of any vanilla javascript ones.

**TLDR:** How can I remove dynamic data in string before a value in that string (in this example everything before the `example.com`)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need lodash to do that

```
var str = 'https://d1yww.cloudfront.net/9MA=/670x670/example.com/image/5119b3905.jpg'
str.substr(str.indexOf('example.com'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search for a Regular Expression

For [Example](https://regex101.com/r/qV3iR4/2):

`/\/([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b)\//g`

and look for the second match

Comment: Thanks this looks helpful, and thanks for the example, I haven't worked too much with regex but looks like it will be my solution